# Display data with buttons on a row for each data entry

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, listview

I'm new to objective c and I'm coming from Android. In Android, when you want to display data with buttons you use a `ListView` and a custom `ArrayAdapter` in combination to achieve this.

What I want to do is the following. I'm downloading datasets from a database. Let's just say, I'm downloading usernames here.

Now, for each username, I want to display it in a row and have two buttons next to the name. Edit and Delete. I thought about a `TableRow` but the problem would be, that the buttons need to correspond with the name. Means: If I press delete on the button, the name entry should be deleted also.

I also need to give the entry a custom id. I can't use the simple `tag` since it can't be an integer. It hast o be a `NSString` or something like that. What would be the best way to do it. Here is an image of what it would look like in Android what I want to achieve.

I also need to create all of this in a `UIViewController` since I don't need only a list, but also a button to add new entries. So one UIButton to add entrys and then a `ListView` with entries and buttons next to each other. This is the picture with the example

[image]

This is just an example.

I also don't want a solution. I just want to know the way to do it. So please no complete code! Thanks. Links to tutorials are encouraged. What is the equivalent of a `ListView` in iOS? How is it called?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this create custom class below:-

Also for this you have to add nib manually and named as yourTableCell.xib. it should not come automatically while adding new UITableViewCell.

```
    @interface yourTableCell : UITableViewCell

    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *subjectLbl;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *subjectBtn;    

    @end
```

Now in you nib select tableviewcell and mention class name inside identity inspector of custom class (yourTableCell)

Now in your view controller of tableview connect datasource and delegate Now load your tableviewcell xib like this below:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
    yourTableCell *cell = (yourTableCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id oneObject in nib)
        {
            if([oneObject isKindOfClass:[yourTableCell class]])
                cell = (yourTableCell *)oneObject;
        }

//Now you can access your label and button as well and perform whatever you want to perform
cell.subjectLbl.text=@"youValue";
cell.subjectBtn.title=@"yourTitle";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Read about the UITableView, and custom UITableViewCell. That's the best way to achieve this. Here are some links:

1. [http://mobile.tutsplus.com/](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)
2. [RAYWENDERLICH Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview)
3. [iOS Programming Tutorials](http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-use-custom-uitableviewcell.html)

You can google some more.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. But the problem is that I already found tutorials like that. I'm searching for some that do it 100% programmatically and without storyboards

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a class that subclasses the UITableViewCell and
>   overwrite init method...In which you can create your own custom
>   tableview cell. With out using storyboard or xib...